# QMK Toolbox: No HID console devices connected when trying to upload firmware to keyboard

Tags: keyboard, teensy, atmega32, qmk, qmk-firmware

[The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9I3c.png) would normally show "list all devices", so I’m assuming it says, "No HID console devices connected" because for some reason it is not recognizing my [ATmega32U4](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATmega32U4) chip.

I have tried:

- Using three wires. I have already confirmed two of the three I had were able to transfer data and not just voltage by searching up the type of wires and what brand they come/what they're used for.
- reinstalling QMK Toolbox (software used to upload firmware to keyboards)
- Confirmed with [Device Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager) that my ports were still working
- installed drivers both times when installing

I am stumped and don't have any clue what I'm doing wrong. I have the ATmega32U4 board selected and have checked my [Teensy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arduino_boards_and_compatible_systems#Software-compatibility_only) chip and its the same and am using Windows.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You have the .hex file so using AVRDUDE directly on the command-line should work. All depending, double clicking the reset button first may be necessary to bring it into bootloader mode (times out after 8 seconds).